# Shinyapp not plotting because of x-axis values, but works in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

Looks simple but I can't figure out why ggplot won't display properly in Shiny.
The ggplot code works fine in R, but when I put it in Shiny it doesn't display. It has something to do with how the x-axis year data, I have converted to numeric. I have attached data screenshots too.

Dataequip is an uploaded CSV file that goes through transformations and calculations. When I create a  minimal shiny reprex it works. In short somehow Shiny takes my numeric year values and is turning them into NA. I have tried data.tables, recreate data.table bottom up, re-doing the index, rename cols but it still passes as NA in Shiny.

Thanks!

```
Error message:
Warning in seq.default(min(plot_data$Year), max(plot_data$Year), by = 1) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in seq.default: 'from' must be a finite number
```

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(title = "Test", id = "tabs",
             
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        fileInput("file", "Upload data",
                                  accept = c(
                                    "text/csv",
                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                    ".csv")
                        ),
                        textInput("maintitlename", "Title"),
                      ),
                      mainPanel( 
                        plotOutput("chart1"),
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  userfile <- reactive({
    input$file
  })
  
  filereact <- reactive({
    read.table(
      file = userfile()$datapath,
      sep = ',',
      header = T,
      stringsAsFactors = T
    )
  })
  
  tabsnames <- reactive({
    names(filereact())
  })
  
  observeEvent(userfile(),{
  
    Equipmentdata <- as.data.frame(filereact()) 
    
#lots of calculations
    
    #plotting
    non_cumulativeequip <- colSums(values[, 8:ncol(values)])
    
    # Calculate the cumulative sum by year
    cumulativeequip <- cumsum(non_cumulativeequip)
    
    # Create a data frame for plotting
    plot_data <- data.frame(Year = colnames(values)[8:ncol(values)],
                                 Cumulative = cumulativeequip)
    
    output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Year, y = Cumulative, group = 1)) +
        geom_line(size = 0.8) +
        labs(x = "Year", y = "Cumulative $") +
        ggtitle("Test") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix = "$"),
                           breaks = seq(0, max(plot_data$Cumulative), by = 50000000)) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(plot_data$Year), max(plot_data$Year), by = 1)) +
        theme(text = element_text(size = 14))
    })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: (1) What is `plot_dataequip`? (2) You say it doesn't work in shiny but works on the console, I'm very confused, since nothing in this plot uses anything from a shiny context. This would benefit from reproducible sample data and likely a working minimal shiny reprex, not just a portion of one. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your response (1) I have provided the clean code and logic leading up to the plotting so you know what plot_data is. (2) the code after observeEvent(userfile() is what I mean. If I take this code outside of Shiny the plot works fine.

Comment: Don’t nest your reactives. That’s a recipe for disaster. Convert `plot_data` to a reactive and move `output$chart1` into the body of the server function itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Extract numeric values from column names
numeric_values <- str_extract(colnames(values)[8:ncol(capital_values)], "\\d+")

# Convert extracted values to numeric
Year <- as.numeric(numeric_values)

# Create the plot_dataequip data frame
plot_data <- data.frame(Year = Year, Cumulative = cumulativeequip)
```